# TensorFlow dependencies needed. How to run TensorFlow on Windows

Tags: windows, gpu, tensorflow

I am interested in getting TensorFlow to run on Windows, however at present I realize that this is not possible due to some of the dependencies not being usable with Windows, e.g. Bazel.

The need arises because as I currently understand it the only way to access the GPU from TensorFlow is via a non-virtual install of Linux. I do realize I can dual boot into a Linux install, but would prefer to avoid that route.

To resolve the problem I am in need of the entire dependency chain to build TensorFlow as was wondering if this already existed.

I also realize that I can capture the build output when building from source as a solid start, but would like to avoid that work if it is already known.

There is a beta of Bazel that runs on Windows - https://github.com/dslomov/bazel-windows

See related GitHub Issue to run TensorFlow on Windows. - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17

Another reason to run on Windows is the possibility to port to Xbox One.

I found a possible answer, still need to check it. This will generate a dependency graph as a dot file.

```sh
$ bazel query 'deps(//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package)' --output graph > tensorflow.dependency.dot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are now three main options for building and/or running TensorFlow on Windows:

- You can install a GPU-enabled PIP package of TensorFlow 0.12rc0 from PyPI: `pip install tensorflow-gpu`
- You can build the GPU-enabled PIP package yourself using the [experimental CMake build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/d6b25985ac219a6e58d186a2beb74d5e8d9e4533/tensorflow/contrib/cmake). This also gives you the ability to work with TensorFlow in Visual Studio. The documentation for this build can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d6b25985ac219a6e58d186a2beb74d5e8d9e4533/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md).
- There is preliminary support for building TensorFlow using [Bazel for Windows](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/windows.html). However, we are still ironing out some bugs with this build.

Comment: Thanks. I will check these out when I get some time and if one works will accept this as the answer. I have been holding off on using TensorFlow until I can get TensorFlow to work on Windows and access the GPU. If this works on my system I will be spending more time with TensorFlow and passing along the good news.

Comment: Still have not had time to check these in detail, but I know you are judicial about your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want one way to run TensorFlow under Windows is to install a virtual machine (VMWare player v12 is free to use for non-commercial) and then install Ubuntu in that and finally TensorFlow in Ubuntu. Works well for me.

Comment: Thanks. I have been using Debian on VMWare for years and it works great for TensorFlow for CPU variation. The problem is that one cannot use the GPU with a type 2 hypervisor. I have a few more options to look into, with the top one being to boot Linux from a thumb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Since the begin of 2017, Tensorflow is now [officially supported on Windows and can be installed via pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows):

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

or by fetching packages directly (pick the one that matches your needs, e.g. x64/gpu)

```
# x86 / CPU
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl

# x64 / CPU
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
# x64 / GPU
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```