# How to install TensorFlow on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am starting to work with TensorFlow library for deep learning, https://www.tensorflow.org/.

I found a explicit guide to work on it on linux and Mac but I did not find how to work with it under Windows. I try over the net, but the information are lacking.

I use Visual Studio 2015 for my projects, and I am trying to compile the library with Visual studio Compiler VC14.

How to install it and to use it under Windows?

Can I use [Bazel for Windows](https://github.com/dslomov/bazel-windows)  for production use?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> How to install TensorFlow and to use it under Windows?

**Updated on 8/4/16**

Windows 10 now has a [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) Bash environment, AKA [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about), available as a standard option (as opposed to [Insider Preview updates for developers](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview)). (StackOverflow tag [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl)) This option came with the [Windows 10 anniversary update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history) (Version 1607) released on 8/2/2016. This allows the use of [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) to install software packages such as [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

Note: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows does not have access to the GPU, so all of the GPU options for installing TensorFlow will not work.

The dated [installation instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows are basically correct, but only these steps are necessary:
Prerequisites
Enable the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature (GUI)
Reboot when prompted
Run Bash on Windows

Steps no longer needed:
Turn on Developer Mode
Enable the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature (command-line)

Then install TensorFlow using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev
sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

and now test TensorFlow

```
$ python3
...
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
Hello, TensorFlow!
>>> a = tf.constant(10)
>>> b = tf.constant(32)
>>> print(sess.run(a + b))
42
>>> exit()
```

and run an actual neural network

```
python3 -m tensorflow.models.image.mnist.convolutional
```

### Earlier Answer

After learning about the developer preview of Bash on Windows.

See [Playing with TensorFlow on Windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlayingWithTensorFlowOnWindows.aspx) by Scott Hanselman which uses [Bash on Windows 10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx)

### Original Answer

**Bazel is the problem**

TensorFlow is not made with [build automation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) such as [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), but with Google's in-house build tool [Bazel](http://bazel.io/faq.html). Bazel only works on systems based on [Unix](http://www.unix.org/) such as [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) and [OS X](http://www.apple.com/osx/what-is/).

Since the current published/known means to build TensorFlow uses [Bazel](http://bazel.io/) and Bazel does not work on Windows, one can not install or run TensorFlow natively on Windows.

From [Bazel FAQ](http://bazel.io/faq.html)

> What about Windows?
>
> Due to its UNIX heritage, porting Bazel to Windows is significant
>   work. For example, Bazel uses symlinks extensively, which has varying
>   levels of support across Windows versions.
>
> We are currently actively working on improving Windows support, but
>   it's still ways from being usable.

*Status*

See: [TensorFlow issue #17](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17)
See: [Bazel issue #276](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/276)

### Solutions

The solutions are listed in the order of complexity and work needed; from about an hour to may not even work.

1. *[Docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker)*
   ~ 1 hour

[Docker installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-installation)

Docker is a system to build self contained versions of a Linux operating system running on your machine. When you install and run TensorFlow via Docker it completely isolates the installation from pre-existing packages on your machine.

Also look at [TensorFlow - which Docker image to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34694701/1243762)

2. *OS X*
   ~ 1 hour

If you have a current Mac running OS X then see: [Installation for Mac OS X](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#installation-for-mac-os-x)

3. *Linux*

The [recommend Linux system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664602/building-new-tensorflow-op-is-there-a-build-system-standard) tends to be [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/) ([Download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)).

a. Virtual Machine - [Hardware Virtualization - Full Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_virtualization#Full_virtualization)
     ~ 3 hours

Download and install a virtual machine such as the commercial [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) or the free [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), after which you can install Linux and then install TensorFlow.

When you go to install TensorFlow you will be using [Pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) - Python's package management system. Visual Studio users should think NuGet. The packages are known as [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/).

See: [Pip Installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#overview)

If you need to build from the source then see: [Installing From Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources)
~ 4 hours

Note: If you plan on using a Virtual Machine and have never done so before, consider using the Docker option instead, since Docker is the Virtual Machine, OS and TensorFlow all packaged together.

b. [Dual boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting)
     ~ 3 hours

If you want to run TensorFlow on the same machine that you have Windows and make use of the GPU version then you will most likely have to use this option as running on a hosted Virtual Machine, [Type 2 hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor), will not allow you access to the GPU.

4. *Remote machine*
   ~ 4 hours

If you have [remote access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software) to another machine that you can install the Linux OS and TensorFlow software on and allow remote connections to, then you can use your Windows machine to present the remote machine as an application running on Windows.

5. *Cloud Service*
   I have no experience with this. Please edit answer if you know.

[Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) services such as [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) are being used.

From [TensorFlow Features](https://www.tensorflow.org/)

> Want to run the model as a service in the cloud?
>   Containerize with Docker and TensorFlow just works.

From [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

> Running Docker on AWS provides a highly reliable, low-cost way to
>   quickly build, ship, and run distributed applications at scale. Deploy
>   Docker using AMIs from the AWS Marketplace.

6. Wait for Bazel to work on Windows.

Currently it appears the only hold up is Bazel, however [Bazel's roadmap](http://bazel.io/roadmap.html) list working on Windows should be available this year.

There are two features listed for Windows:

```
2016‑02  Bazel can bootstrap itself on Windows without requiring admin privileges.  

2016‑12  Full Windows support for Android: Android feature set is identical for Windows and Linux/OS X.
```

7. Build TensorFlow by hand.
   A few days or more depending on you skill level. I gave up on this one; too many subprojects to build and files to locate.

Remember that Bazel is only used to build TensorFlow. If you get the commands Bazel runs and the correct source code and libraries you should be able to build TensorFlow on Windows. See: [How do I get the commands executed by Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33983711/1243762).

While I have not researched this more, you can look at the [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) info for needed files and info on how to they build it for testing. ([Readme](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/README.md)) ([site](http://ci.tensorflow.org/))

8. Build Bazel on Windows
   A few days or more depending on you skill level. I gave up on this one also; could not find the necessary source files needed for Windows.

There is a public experimental source code version of [Bazel that boots on Windows](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/site/docs/windows.md). You may be able to leverage this into getting Bazel to work on Windows, etc.

Also these solutions require the use of [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) which adds another layer of complexity.

9. Use alternative build system such as Make
   If you get this one to work I would like to see in on GitHub.

This currently does not exist for TensorFlow. It is a feature request.

See: [TensorFlow issue 380](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/380)

10. Cross Build
    If you get this one to work I would like to see in on GitHub.

You build TensorFlow on Linux using Bazel but change the build process to output a wheel that can be installed on Windows. This will require detailed knowledge of Bazel to change the configuration, and locating the source code and libraries that work with Windows. An option I would only suggest as a last resort. It may not even be possible.

11. Run on the new Windows Subsystem for Linux.

See: [Windows Subsystem for Linux Overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/)

You will know as much as I do by reading the referenced article.

> Can I use Bazel for Windows for production use?

Since it is experimental software I would not use on a production machine.

Remember that you only need Bazel to build TensorFlow. So use the experimental code on a non production machine to build the [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com/), then install the wheel on a production machine. See: [Pip Installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation)

TLDR;

Currently I have several versions for learning. Most use a VMWare 7.1 Workstation to host Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or Ubuntu 15 or Debian. I also have one dual boot of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Windows machine to access the GPU as the machine with VMware does not have the proper GPU. I would recommend that you give these machines at least 8G of memory either as RAM or RAM and swap space as I have run out of memory a few times.

Comment: Very informative, thank you, +1. I think using it on remote linux desktop is the best solution.

Comment: Nice option and one I have not listed. Some people are also using cloud services such as [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/).

Comment: did you try the dmtk of Windows? what do you think about the feature compared to the  tensorflow?

Comment: I am only putting all this detail into this answer because you gave me a pretext to do so and it should be in one place and made public. StackOverflow Q&A get a high Google listing.

Comment: No I have not tired [DMTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DMTK) as I am self learning from the ground up. To learn the basics I am currently translating [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) into F# which is also helping me learn Python and understand the [numpy package](http://www.numpy.org/) and watching [Andrew Ng videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzxYlbK2c7E).

Comment: `what do you think about the feature compared to the TensorFlow?` I would actually put money on [Memristor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristor). Once these become mainstream and are shown to work with neural networks, we will be saying goodbye to CPU/GPU neural network solutions. The deep learning concepts will obviously translate and maybe even tools like TensorBoard, but the rest I see going the way of the [Dodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodo)

Comment: Of interest: You will be able to run Ubuntu bash natively on [Windows 10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx).

Comment: Of interest: [Windows Subsystem for Linux Overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/)

Comment: Of interest: [Playing with TensorFlow on Windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlayingWithTensorFlowOnWindows.aspx) by Scott Hanselman. This uses [Bash on Windows 10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx)

Comment: Of interest: [VIDEO: How to run Linux and Bash on "Windows 10 Anniversary Update"](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VIDEOHowToRunLinuxAndBashOnWindows10AnniversaryUpdate.aspx)

Comment: Of interest: [Ubuntu shell access to system GPU. Ability to run CUDA for use in Machine Learning applications.](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13250010-ubuntu-shell-access-to-system-gpu-ability-to-run). If you want it, vote on it at the link provided.

Comment: Great, properly uses 100% of all CPUs and hyperthreads; core i7-6700HQ - 4 CPUs (8 hyperthreads).

Comment: Of interest: [TensorFlow dependencies needed. How to run TensorFlow on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40848593/1243762) I have not tested these yet, but plan to do so and will update answer when I do.

Comment: Should be just `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`

Answer (score 17):

I can confirm that it works in the Windows Subsystem for Linux!
And it is also very straightforward.

In the Ubuntu Bash on Windows 10, first update the package index:

```
apt-get update
```

Then install pip for Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
```

Install tensorflow:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The package is now installed an you can run the CNN sample on the MNIST set:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/image/mnist

python convolutional.py
```

I just tested the CPU package for now.

I blogged about it: http://blog.mosthege.net/2016/05/11/running-tensorflow-with-native-linux-binaries-in-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

cheers

~michael

Comment: When type "cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/image/mnist", console just says "no such a file or directory" but I can access the address by manually cd one layer by layer. Wonder if you also have this problem.

Answer (score 8):

*Sorry for the excavation, but this question is quite popular, and now it has a different answer.*

Google officially announced the addition of Windows (7, 10, and Server 2016) support for TensorFlow:
[developers.googleblog.com](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/tensorflow-0-12-adds-support-for-windows.html)

The Python module can be installed using pip with a single command:

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow
```

And if you need GPU support:

```
 C:\> pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

[TensorFlow manual - How to install pip on windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation-on-windows)

Another useful information are included in release notes:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases

**UPD:** As @m02ph3u5 right mentioned in the comments TF for windows supports only Python 3.5.x [Installing TensorFlow on Windows with native pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#installing_with_native_pip)

Comment: You should mention that atm the official windows version supports **Python 3.5 ONLY**

Answer (score 6):

## Installing TensorFlow

TensorFlow currently supports only Python 3.5 64-bit. Both CPU and GPU are supported. Here are some installation instructions assuming you do not have Python 3.5 64-bit:

1. Download and install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587 (required by Python 3.5 and TensorFlow)
2. Download and install Python 3.5 64-bit: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-amd64.exe
3. Install pip as follows: download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py, then run `python get-pip.py`
4. Install TensorFlow with either `pip install tensorflow` (CPU version) or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` (GPU version --> requires CUDA to be installed).

---

## Testing TensorFlow

You can now run something like following to test whether TensorFlow is working fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
a = tf.constant(10)
b = tf.constant(32)
print(sess.run(a + b))
```

TensorFlow comes with a few models, which are located in `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\` (assuming you installed python in `C:\Python35`). For example, you can run in the console:

```
python -m tensorflow.models.image.mnist.convolutional
```

or

```
python C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\image\mnist\convolutional.py
```

---

## Limitations of TensorFlow on Windows

Initial support for building TensorFlow on Microsoft Windows was added on  2016-10-05 in commit [2098b9abcf20d2c9694055bbfd6997bc00b73578](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/2098b9abcf20d2c9694055bbfd6997bc00b73578):

> This PR contains an initial version of support for building TensorFlow
>   (CPU only) on Windows using CMake. It includes documentation for
>   building with CMake on Windows, platform-specific code for
>   implementing core functions on Windows, and CMake rules for building
>   the C++ example trainer program and a PIP package (Python 3.5 only).
>   The CMake rules support building TensorFlow with Visual Studio 2015.
>
> Windows support is a work in progress, and we welcome your feedback
>   and contributions.
>
> For full details of the features currently supported and instructions
>   for how to build TensorFlow on Windows, please see the file
>   [`tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md).

The Microsoft Windows support was introduced in TensorFlow in version 0.12 RC0 ([release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/0.12.0-rc0)):

> TensorFlow now builds and runs on Microsoft Windows (tested on Windows 10, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2016). Supported languages include Python (via a pip package) and C++. CUDA 8.0 and cuDNN 5.1 are supported for GPU acceleration. Known limitations include: It is not currently possible to load a custom op library. The GCS and HDFS file systems are not currently supported. The following ops are not currently implemented: DepthwiseConv2dNative, DepthwiseConv2dNativeBackpropFilter, DepthwiseConv2dNativeBackpropInput, Dequantize, Digamma, Erf, Erfc, Igamma, Igammac, Lgamma, Polygamma, QuantizeAndDequantize, QuantizedAvgPool, QuantizedBatchNomWithGlobalNormalization, QuantizedBiasAdd, QuantizedConcat, QuantizedConv2D, QuantizedMatmul, QuantizedMaxPool, QuantizeDownAndShrinkRange, QuantizedRelu, QuantizedRelu6, QuantizedReshape, QuantizeV2, RequantizationRange, and Requantize.

Answer (score 5):

Now Tensorflow is officially supported in Windows, you can install it using `pip` command of Python 3.5 without compile it yourself

CPU Version

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

*cp35* indicates *python 3.5* wheel, *0.12.0* the version, you can edit these according your preference, or to install latest CPU version available you can use

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

GPU Version

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

*cp35* indicates *python 3.5* wheel, *0.12.0* the version, you can edit these according your preference, or to install latest GPU version available you can use

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

[More Info](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation-on-windows)

Comment: `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` will do for tf 1.1+

Answer (score 3):

Following may work for you: install Virtual Box, create Linux VM and install Linux into it. I'd recommend Ubuntu, because Google often uses it internally. Then, install TensorFlow in Linux VM.

Comment: Yes, this is the direct solution to have, Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't at the moment. The problem is that tensorflow uses the bazel build [another Google internal tool that has been exposed as an open source project](http://bazel.io/docs/install.html) and it has only support for mac and unix.
Until bazel is ported to windows or another build system is added to tensorflow there is a little chance to run tensorflow natively on windows.

That said you can install virtualbox and then install docker-machine and run a linux container with tensorflow inside it.

Comment: Can I port manually the Bazel build tool to windows? Thanks for your informative advice, +1.

Comment: Can I use [bazel fo WIndows](https://github.com/dslomov/bazel-windows) for production uses?

Comment: @ProEns08 The github page clearly warns to _not_ use this for serious purposes.

Comment: Yes, It looks like standard warning. Just like GPL or BSD licenses warnings. But, there is one that had tried it for serious pruposes?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install TensorFlow on Win8.1 without Docker using advice from
https://discussions.udacity.com/t/windows-tensorflow-and-visual-studio-2015/45636

I tried a lot of stuff before that, and i won't try to install it twice but here is what i did:
- install VS2015 (make sure Visual C++ installed as well)
- install Python Tools for VS2015
- install Python2.7 with Anaconda2
- install pip and conda for Python
- install numpy with pip inside VS2015
- install tensorflow with pip inside VS2015

i didn't manage to do it with Python3.5

I managed also to install on Win8.1 via Cloud9
There is a video tutorial on Youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMtrOIPLpR0

EDIT: actually for the above, (not Cloud9 which is fine) i have problems:
TensorFlow LOOKS LIKE it's installed (i can see it in the list of modules installed in VS2015 when clicking in Solution Explorer on Python 64-bit 2.7)
*but* if i type in a script or in Python Interactive `import tensorflow as TF` then i get an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Fagui\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Fagui\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
  File "C:\Users\Fagui\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\framework_lib.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "C:\Users\Fagui\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import versions
  File "C:\Users\Fagui\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\versions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Fagui\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Fagui\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful and a quick solution, Thank you,+1.

Answer (score 2):

As of writing this answer, I wasn't able to get tensorflow to install properly with python version 3.5.2.  Reverting to [python 3.5.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) did the trick.

Then I was able to install with

> C:> pip install tensorflow

Answer (score 2):

If you have already installed anaconda on your windows, there is an easier way as I found out:

```
conda create --name snakes python=3
```

Then

```
activate snakes
```

Then

```
pip install tensorflow
```

This is similar to virtualenv and I found this helpful.

Comment: Should be explicitly `conda create --name snakes python=3.5` for only 3.5 is supported

Answer (score -1):

Follow this [link](http://bottomstack.com/installing-tensorflow-windows-visual-studio/) to install Tensorflow on Windows and you can also use it in Visual Studio