# Whl file for tensorflow installation on windows

Tags: tensorflow

I installed pip via get-pip.py script

```
$ python get-pip.py --proxy="proxy.intranet.com:8080"
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 559kB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 2.9MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Successfully installed pip-8.1.2 wheel-0.29.0
```

it worked fine. On upgrade, it seemed to be the latest version.

```
$ python -m pip install -U pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

now, when I try to install tensorflow on windows using the below command, it doesn't work.

```
$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
**tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform**.
```

I tried to search a wheel file for windows, but couldn't find it. Anyone knows the locations to the whl file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is just no Windows version for Windows for the time being. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785414/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-windows for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow is only compatible with 64bit. Ensure that the Python installation is not 32bit.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks like a comment to the question instead of an answer. If you intend to comment, you need to have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow is [now available](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/tensorflow-0-12-adds-support-for-windows.html) on Windows, from version 0.12 onwards. You can install the PIP package from PyPI, using the following command (for the CPU-only build):

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow
```

...or the following command if you have a CUDA 8.0-compatible GPU:

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: one issue with this approach is that for cpu it will not install the tensorflow version with advanced instruction set support such as avx2. it will still work though and a good start for beginners considering custom building is not trivial.