# How to use libtensorflow-lite.a on Raspi 3?

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, tensorflow-lite

I want to install TensorFlow Lite on the Raspi.

I assume I can first `pip install` the prebuilt TensorFlow for the Raspi. I'm reading the instructions to cross compile TensorFlow Lite [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/rpi), but I have no idea what to do after generating `libtensorflow-lite.a`.

Comment: Take a look at a similar question. The answers describe how to build python bindings for tflite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902067/how-to-import-the-tensorflow-lite-interpreter-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libtensorflow-lite.a should be used for C++ inference code.

There is a [minimal example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal/minimal.cc) of TFLite. You can find Makefile from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile#L280). You might also want to check [C++ API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc/class/tflite/interpreter).