# is there a way to use tensorflow on windows 10 without slowing it down with a virtual machine?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow currently on a virtualbox Linux VM, on a native windows pc.

This is slow.

I've read what I could find about this (e.g.: [How to install TensorFlow on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785414/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-windows))

However, they suggest using a Virtual Machine, which is maybe 10 times slower compared to a native OS.

Is there a way to use Tensorflow just in windows directly?

Comment: You may want to ask this on the GitHub issues page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We recently [announced](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/tensorflow-0-12-adds-support-for-windows.html) TensorFlow 0.12, which is the first version that comes with Windows support and pre-built packages for Windows. It supports Python 3.5 and GPU acceleration with GPUs that support CUDA 8.0. To install the Python package on Windows you can use pip:

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow
```

To install the GPU-acclerated version there is a different package:

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow-gpu
```